# Please tell what approach should be used for desktop application

Tags: c#

I am planing to develop desktop application that will have multiple logins and according to that login type options/From view will be displayed.

I have done database login part now its turn of view

How can i establish that what i have in my mind that

1. Drag and drop all required controls and make them visible = false and check which type of login is that and display accordingly
2. Create separate forms and display one by one as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it depends on numbers.

If u have many diffrent user roles and they share only a few controls then it would be easier to make diffrent form / panel for each user type. This approach is quite dangerous since when you want to change common control u would be forced to do it in all forms / panels.

Thats why i would recommend to group application logic into custom controls and then build GUI from them. *For example:* if you have two user types ( let's say boss and employee ) then you can build form with shared controls / logic and two user controls (bossControl, employeeControl) with functions for boss and employee. Then after login check you add matching user control to GUI.

Answer (score 3):

You sound like you are new to C# forms programming. I suggest looking at some tutorials or a book like this [Windows Forms Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321116208)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make one form and make control visible/invisible or enable/disable control.

> Create separate forms and display one
>   by one as required

it will be very difficult for you to manage and extend in future.